# Simple Oracle JOIN (+) to HSQLDB

Tags: sql, join, hsqldb

How to convert this query to work in HSQLDB?

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL D1, DUAL D2 WHERE D1.dummy = D2.dummy(+)
```

Thanks

Comment: See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html#N10372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(+)` is Oracle's deprecated version of writing an outer join. In HSQLDB you use a standard ANSI SQL `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DUAL D1
   left outer join DUAL D2 on D1.dummy = D2.dummy;
```

You should stop using th e `(+)` in Oracle as well.